# HTTP authentication, request received in quick succession

Tags: http, authentication, timestamp, nonce

HTTP request may be received in quick succession, for avoiding re-running the while protocol for each request, the server nonce may be re-used (timestamp for nonce to determine the window in which client request are valid) by the client for multiple requests.

What are pros and cons using this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pros of re-using a nonce](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-4.3) are that it does take less resources for maintaining and checking valid nonces and can avoid authentication failures for pipelined requests:

> […] the method
> chosen for generating and checking the nonce also has performance and
> resource implications.  For example, a server may choose to allow
> each nonce value to be used only once by maintaining a record of
> whether or not each recently issued nonce has been returned and
> sending a next-nonce directive in the Authentication-Info header
> field of every response. This protects against even an immediate
> replay attack, but has a high cost checking nonce values, and perhaps
> more important will cause authentication failures for any pipelined
> requests (presumably returning a stale nonce indication).

However, the cons are that [replay attacks](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-4.5) are more probable than with one-time nonces:

> For applications where no possibility of replay attack can be
> tolerated the server can use one-time nonce values which will not be
> honored for a second use. This requires the overhead of the server
> remembering which nonce values have been used until the nonce time-
> stamp (and hence the digest built with it) has expired, but it
> effectively protects against replay attacks.